# Extbase Property Mapping for arrays

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to use a Array Object inside a Fluid form using Property Mapper. The products are dynamic added if user clicks an "add_product" link:

```
<f:form action="property" name="newOrder" object="{newOrder}">

    <f:for each="{newOrder.orderProduct}" as="orderProduct" iteration="iterator">
        <f:form.hidden property="orderProduct.{iterator.index}.product" value="8" />
        <h3>OrderProduct: {orderProduct.product.title}</h3>
    </f:for>
    <f:form.hidden name="add_product" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</f:form>
```

What I get after submit is this exception.

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1297759968: 
Exception while property mapping at property path "orderProduct.0":
Property "product" was not found in target object of type "MyVendor\MyShop\Domain\Model\Product".
```

The hidden field resolves to: `<input name="tx_myshop_pi1[newOrder][orderProduct][0][product]" value="8" type="hidden">` (the static value of 8 is just to simplify the example)

I also tried `key="key"` instead of iterator, empty brackets `orderProduct[]`, using name instead of property without result.

This is the (simplified) Debug output:

```
newOrder (MyVendor\MyShop\Domain\Model\ShopOrder)
   => orderProduct (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage)
      3222112 => MyVendor\MyShop\Domain\Model\OrderProduct
              product => MyVendor\MyShop\Domain\Model\Product
                     uid => 8
                     title => 'Product1'
```

This is the Model Code:

- ShopOrder https://pastebin.com/YN7X37ei
- OrderProduct https://pastebin.com/zFyztLAQ

For the Property Mapper, I tried a lot of configurations without success. In my opinion this should work but it does not:

```
public function initializePropertyAction()
{
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\PropertyMappingConfiguration $propertyMappingConfiguration */
    $propertyMappingConfiguration = $this->arguments['newOrder']->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
    $propertyMappingConfiguration->allowAllProperties();
    $propertyMappingConfiguration->setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter',
        PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED,
        TRUE);

    $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('orderProduct')->allowAllProperties();
    $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('orderProduct')->setTypeConverterOption(
        'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter',
        PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED,
        TRUE
    );

    //workaround from https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61628
    for ($i = 0; $i < 99; $i++) {
        $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('orderProduct.' . $i)->allowAllProperties();
        $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('orderProduct.' . $i . '.*')->allowAllProperties();
        $propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('orderProduct.' . $i)->setTypeConverterOption(
            'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter',
            PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED,
            TRUE
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that `tx_myshop_pi1[newOrder][orderProduct][0]` is from class Product? Because this is what the exception says. And I assume that your model Product does not contain an attribute named product.

Comment: tx_myshop_pi1[newOrder][orderProduct][0] is from class ObjectStorage, tx_myshop_pi1[newOrder][orderProduct][0][product] is from class Product. I added the pastebin Links for the Model Code - you can check if this is the error source. 
If there is some kind of typecasting necessary I could use some help on how to do this.

Comment: Solved - error was in Model, not in PropertyMapping

Comment: tx_myshop_pi1[newOrder][orderProduct] is from class ObjectStorage. [0] is already the first item in the storage. But yeah, you've fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this, in my case for a question with a dynamic number of answers having two fields, each:

```
$propertyMappingConfiguration = $this->arguments->getArgument('question')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
$propertyMappingConfiguration->skipProperties('category');
$propertyMappingConfiguration->allowProperties('answers');         
$propertyMappingConfiguration->forProperty('answers.*')->allowProperties('answerField1', 'answerField2');
$propertyMappingConfiguration->allowCreationForSubProperty('answers.*');
$propertyMappingConfiguration->allowModificationForSubProperty('answers.*');
```

Comment: 'allowCreationForSubProperty' is not available in 7.6 - but I think the setTypeConverterOption I use is doing the same?